# Paid publication fee and now no contact from journal: what should I do?

Tags: publications, journals, fees

My situation is the following: I submitted an article to a journal which appeared in Scimago, the article got accepted, and they charged a fee for publication costs. I have now paid this fee from personal money using PayPal.

The problem is that it has been nearly two weeks since I made the payment and I have not received any email about it. I have checked my account and the payment has been made, wrote an email to the editor in charge within a lapse of two days, and have received no answer at all.

I am pretty worried about this situation, but how can I deal with it? I have tried to call their contact number and also gotten no answer at all.  Should I continue sending emails to the other editors of this journal or just wait until they give me an answer? I would not like to sound like I am anxious, but I believe it is pretty bad that at least they do not give an answer if they receive the money or not.

Comment: Do you mean that you paid with your own money and not with university funds?

Comment: I've done some cleanup on the post; please feel free to revert any aspects that you feel damaged the original question.

Comment: Have to ask: is there any chance this is a predatory journal? Being listed in a ranking doesn't necessarily rule this out. Do they publish what you regard as good work? Do well known experts in your field publish there? Did your interactions with the journal give you confidence that their peer review process is thorough?

Comment: It is not a predatory journal, I have checked it; also the list of reviewers were well known in the field. The peer review also gives useful insight

Answer (score 9):

Based on the time of year, if the journal is based in the US or Europe, it might be that the editor and staff are on vacation. You have confirmed with your bank that they have received funds, so I wouldn't worry too much. Give them a week or two, and then follow up more strenuously.

Comment: Also remember that hardcopy publications take months from acceptance to publication.

Comment: it is an online publication, published monthly

Comment: @keshlam Then they can simply state that by mail ; Layla: Since you paid via paypal you can get a refund within some timeframe (60 days or so, check it), that gives you a good indication of how long you can wait before making more... "serious" inquiries.